# Angular 9 : Drop file not firing

Tags: angular, file-upload

I want to fire an event after a file is dropped, but the drop event is never fired. On the other hands, all the other events are fired. Here is the code :

```
 **Template**
<angular-file-uploader #fileUpload [config]="config" (change)="onChange($event)" (drop)="onDrop($event)" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" (dragenter)="dragenter($event)" (dragleave)="dragleave($event)">
</angular-file-uploader>

**Component** 
onDrop(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    // Not fired
    console.log('drop');
}

onDragOver(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
   // fired
    console.log('over');
}

dragenter(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    // fired
    console.log('enter',event);
}

dragleave(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    // fired
    console.log('leave', event);
}

 config = {
    multiple: false,
    formatsAllowed: ".pdf",
    maxSize: "15", // in MB
    uploadAPI: '',
    theme: "dragNDrop",
    hideProgressBar: false,
    hideResetBtn: false,
    hideSelectBtn: false,
    hideUploadBtn: true
};
```

Any idea why the drop event is not fired after a file is dropped ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems configuration for angular-file-uploader is missing
Try adding below config in your ts file

```
config = {
    multiple: false,
    formatsAllowed: ".jpg,.png",
    maxSize: "1",
    uploadAPI:  {
      url:"https://example-file-upload-api",
      method:"POST",
      headers: {
     "Content-Type" : "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
     "Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      params: {
        'page': '1'
      },
      responseType: 'blob',
    },
    theme: "dragNDrop",
    hideProgressBar: true,
    hideResetBtn: true,
    hideSelectBtn: true,
    fileNameIndex: true,
    replaceTexts: {
      selectFileBtn: 'Select Files',
      resetBtn: 'Reset',
      uploadBtn: 'Upload',
      dragNDropBox: 'Drag N Drop',
      attachPinBtn: 'Attach Files...',
      afterUploadMsg_success: 'Successfully Uploaded !',
      afterUploadMsg_error: 'Upload Failed !',
      sizeLimit: 'Size Limit'
    }
};
```

Check the config properties according to your requirement.
you can refer the example provided here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader

Comment: The config infos are added but the official documentation is not helpful for my need

Comment: I Tried your code and added above config section in to ts file and it worked perfectly.

Comment: hmm...can you create a blitz ? because the onDrop method is not fired on my side after dropping the file in the Drag N Drop zone ! thanks